# What's the URL to install to my new Dupal 9's dev site?

Tags: installation, phpmyadmin, database-backups, drupal-9

I am trying to make a dev site instead of using live site all the time. In **PhpMyAdmin**, I have created a new db called **drupal9_dev**, username as **drupal_dev** and password then imported the db of my live site. I copied all the files of my live site's directory (**drupal2**) to the new directory called **drupal2_dev** which are located in **/vaw/www/html**. Finally, I updated what's in the **$databases** in **settings.php**, cleared the cache and restarted my httpd (I am using CentOS 7 ).

I believe that's everything I need to make a dev site. My question is, what is the URL I need to type in to install the actual site? Please help me, I have tried everything for the past few weeks but no luck at all.

P.S.  I already have

```
$settings['trusted_host_patterns'] = array( '^.+\.devforms\.org$', '^devforms\.org$', '^devforms\.com$', '^.+\.devforms\.com$', ); 
$settings['file_public_base_url'] = 'devforms.org';
```

In my settings.php but the URL would not work still

in /etc/hosts, I have

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
127.0.0.1     www.forms.org
**my_ip_address**    devforms.org
```

The URL to my live site is my_ip_address/web (forgive me to write my_ip_address instead of the actual address)

Comment: Did you check your httpd config (so that it properly serves drupal2_dev at the specified url) and logs ?